# Jquery functions not working as expected - click | keydown method

Tags: javascript, jquery, click, keydown

I'm building a script that will, from a gallery, scroll and center an image after a mouse/keyboard event.
Once an image is "cliked", only the clicked image will be displayed and center on the screen, all others will be hidden.
Then, the user is able to click again in order to scroll to the next img.

Note: when the last img is fired, we will display the bottom of the page.

Report:

- If we are only using the mouse, the script is working as I want.
- If we are only using the bottom key, the script is working as I want.
- If we are using the keyboard (many times) and after the mouse,
  functions will be lauch many times. I think this is due to the .on
  method (keydown click)

Does any one know how to handle this events to make them work together?

[Here is an Jsfidle/example of it](http://jsfiddle.net/j9z9E/2/)

**HTML**

```
<div id="galleries" class="">
    <div id="pictures-content" class="1">
        <img src="http://www.clipartbest.com/cliparts/RiA/jnd/RiAjnd9iL.png">
    </div>
    <div id="pictures-content" class="2">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/v/N/K/k/N/3/number-2-design-md.png">
    </div>
    <div id="pictures-content" class="3">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/x/B/x/Y/R/L/number-3-md.png">
    </div>
    <div id="pictures-content" class="4">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/K/w/R/r/V/Z/number-4-md.png">
    </div>
    <div id="pictures-content" class="5">
        <img src="http://www.bubblews.com/assets/images/news/23937009_1390558154.png">
    </div>
    <div id="pictures-content" class="6">
        <img src="http://www.olneymiddle.milton-keynes.sch.uk/Year6/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/number-6-md-Copy.png">
    </div>        
    <div id="pictures-content" class="7">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/V/K/h/8/c/A/number-7-md.png">
    </div>
    <div id="pictures-content" class="8">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/M/L/0/g/q/R/red-rounded-with-number-8-md.png">
    </div>
    <div id="pictures-content" class="9">
        <img src="http://www.clker.com/cliparts/h/S/2/m/C/o/red-rounded-with-number-9-md.png">
    </div>
</div><!-- galleries --!>
```

**jQuery**

```
    presentation_mode_stop_scrolling = "off";

    // Calling functions
    $(document).ready(function(){ 

        // Init the dom - add a class number to each img

    init_dom_class();

    var picture_to_center = "";
    var key_press = "";
    var counter =0;
    var max = $("#galleries #pictures-content").length;

    $("#galleries #pictures-content").off('click');
    $("#galleries #pictures-content").on('click',undisplay_center_pictures);

    //quit presentation mode + display all content + init variables on scroll event
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if ((presentation_mode_stop_scrolling === "off")) {
            $("#galleries #pictures-content").on('click');
            var i=1;
            // We are checking if we use to be in the presentation mode to removed it just once 
            // Also we display all the pictures again
            var class_gall= $("#galleries").attr('class');
            // display all content + init variables
            if(class_gall=="picture_presentation") {
                $("#galleries #pictures-content").each(function() {
                    $("#galleries ."+i+" img").animate({opacity:1});
                    i++;
                });
                $("#galleries").removeClass('picture_presentation');
                $("#header").animate({opacity:1});
                $("#description").animate({opacity:1});
                $("#bottom_site").animate({opacity:1});
                key_press == "";
            }
        }
    });

    //quit presentation mode + display all content + init variables on resize event
    $(window).resize(function () {
        if (presentation_mode_stop_scrolling === "off"){
            //quit presentation mode
            var i=1;
            // We are checking if we use to be in the presentation mode to removed it just once 
            // Also we display all the pictures again
            var class_gall= $("#galleries").attr('class');
            if(class_gall=="picture_presentation"){
    //          console.log("QUITTING");
    //          console.log("class_gall: "+class_gall);
                $("#galleries #pictures-content").each(function() {
                    $("#galleries ."+i+" img").animate({opacity:1});
                    i++;
                }); 
                $("#galleries").removeClass('picture_presentation');
                $("#header").animate({opacity:1});
                $("#description").animate({opacity:1});
                $("#bottom_site").animate({opacity:1});
                key_press == "";            
            }       
        }
    }); 

    $(document).keydown(function(eventkeyboard) {
        eventkeyboard.preventDefault();
        //eventkeyboard.which is set by jQuery for those browsers that do not normally support eventkeyboard.keyCode.
        // WE HAVE TO RESET THIS VALUE OTHERWISE THE ANIMATION IS BROKEN
        key_press = "";

        var keyCode = eventkeyboard.keyCode || eventkeyboard.which;
//      KEY UP
        if (keyCode === 38) {

            return false;
        }

//      KEY DOWN        
        if (keyCode === 40) {
//      console.log("key down");
        //  Unbind the click eventkeyboard with the presentation_mode_stop_scrolling variable
//      console.log("presentation_mode_stop_scrolling: "+presentation_mode_stop_scrolling);
            // allow keyboard action when the scrolling animation is completed
            if (presentation_mode_stop_scrolling === "off"){
                // IF EACH OF THE IMAGES ARE VISIBLE WE START FROM THE BOTTOM
                var class_galleries= $("#galleries").attr('class');
                if(class_galleries=="picture_presentation"){
//                  console.log("key down - THERE IS AN ACTIVE IMAGE"); // ACTIVE IMG
                    // THERE IS AN ACTIVE IMAGE
                    key_press = "down_with_a_focus_image"; // define the key pressed
                    var picture_to_center = retrieve_the_selected_img(eventkeyboard,key_press); // get img to center
//                  console.log("picture_to_center: "+picture_to_center);
                    hide_all_website_items_except_img_to_center(picture_to_center); // hide all img except the img to center
                    scroll_to_the_new_picture_to_center(picture_to_center);
                    return false;
                } else {
//                  console.log("key down - THERE ISN'T ANY ACTIVE IMAGE"); // NO ACTIVE IMG
                    key_press = "down_without_any_focused_image"; // define the key pressed
                    var picture_to_center = retrieve_the_selected_img(eventkeyboard,key_press); // get img to center
                    $('#galleries #pictures-content').css({'background-image' : 'none'}); // Removing the background loading img
                    $("#galleries").addClass('picture_presentation'); // Add the presentation
                    hide_all_website_items_except_img_to_center(picture_to_center); // hide all img except the img to center
                    scroll_to_the_new_picture_to_center(picture_to_center);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }

//      KEY LEFT
        if (keyCode === 37) {

            return false;
        }

//      KEY RIGHT       
        if (keyCode === 39) {

            return false;
        }
    });

    // We are calling this function on click event
    function undisplay_center_pictures(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $("#galleries #pictures-content").off('click');
        var class_galleries = $("#galleries").attr('class'); // we check if an image is already center
        // console.log("class_galleries: "+class_galleries);

        var picture_to_center = retrieve_the_selected_img(event); // populate the picture_to_center with the selected img
//      console.log("picture_to_center: "+picture_to_center);

        // Manage the picture_presentation mode and return the next image to center
        if ($("#galleries").attr('class') === "picture_presentation") {
            // no key for the moment
            var new_picture_to_center = show_and_get_new_picture_to_center_and_hide_previous(event,picture_to_center,max);
//          console.log("new_picture_to_center: "+new_picture_to_center);
//          var picture_to_center = show_and_get_new_picture_to_center_and_hide_previous(picture_to_center,max);            
            scroll_to_the_new_picture_to_center(new_picture_to_center);
        } else {
            // hide everything except the img with the picture_to_center class
            hide_all_website_items_except_img_to_center(picture_to_center);         
            scroll_to_the_new_picture_to_center(picture_to_center);
            // ADD THE PICTURE PRESENTATION CLASS TO ENTER TO THE PRESENTATION MODE
            $("#galleries").addClass('picture_presentation');
        }
    };

    // Init the dom - add a class number to each img
    function init_dom_class() {
        var i=1;
        $("#galleries #pictures-content").each(function() {
            $(this).addClass(""+i+"");
            i++;
        });
    };

    // return the selected img
    function retrieve_the_selected_img (event,key_press){
        event.preventDefault();
    // We are using only the mouse for the moment so
    //  console.log("key_press: "+key_press);

        if (key_press == "down_without_any_focused_image") {
    //      var picture_to_center = 1;
            return 1;
        } 
        else if (key_press == "down_with_a_focus_image") {
            $("#galleries #pictures-content img").each(function() {
                var all_class_galleries = $(this).css("opacity");
                if (all_class_galleries==1){
                    picture_to_center = parseInt($(this).parent().attr('class'));
                    // DO SOMETHING ON IMG TO CENTER
                    picture_to_center = picture_to_center+1;
                }   
            });
            return picture_to_center;
        } 
        else {
            // mouse click event
            return parseInt($(event.target).parent().attr('class'));
        }
    };

    // hide everything except the img with the picture_to_center class
    function hide_all_website_items_except_img_to_center(picture_to_center){
        //  console.log(picture_to_center);
        console.log("hide_all_website_items_except_img_to_center");
        //  Make a condition redirect user to bottom of the page on last image and display all content
        if(picture_to_center > parseInt($("#galleries #pictures-content").length)) {
            // FADE IN ALL PICTURES
            z=1;
            $("#galleries #pictures-content").each(function() {
                $("#galleries ."+z+" img").animate({opacity:1});
                z++;
            });
            $("#header").animate({opacity:1});
            $("#description").animate({opacity:1});
            $("#bottom_site").animate({opacity:1});
            // REMOVE THE presentation mode 
            $("#galleries").removeClass('picture_presentation');        
            $("body").scrollTo($(document).height(), 800, {
                onAfter: function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        presentation_mode_stop_scrolling = "off";
    //                  console.log("presentation_mode_stop_scrolling: "+presentation_mode_stop_scrolling);         
                        $("#galleries #pictures-content").on('click',undisplay_center_pictures);                
                    },100);
                }
            });    


        } else {
            $("#galleries #pictures-content").each(function() {
                var all_class_galleries = parseInt($(this).attr('class'));
                if(all_class_galleries!=picture_to_center) {
                    $("#galleries ."+all_class_galleries+" img").animate({opacity:0});
                } else{
        //          $("#galleries ."+all_class_galleries+" img");
                    // With keyboard, we need to display the next img
                    $("#galleries ."+all_class_galleries+" img").animate({opacity:1});
                }
            });
            $("#header").animate({opacity:0});
            $("#description").animate({opacity:0});
            $("#bottom_site").animate({opacity:0});
        }
        return true;
    };

    // Hide the previous current img + Update the picture to center variable with the new img value + return new picture to center
    function show_and_get_new_picture_to_center_and_hide_previous(event,picture_to_center,max){
        event.preventDefault();
        console.log("show_and_get_new_picture_to_center_and_hide_previous");
                    // We hide the previous centered img + get new picture to center id
                    if (picture_to_center < max) {
                        $("#galleries ."+picture_to_center+" img").animate({opacity:0});
                        picture_to_center++; 
                    }
                    else if (picture_to_center == max){
                    // We go to the bottom of the page
                        picture_to_center++; // we increment picture_to_center to go to the bottom of the page
    //                  console.log("We have to scroll to the bottom");
    //                  last_picture = 1;
                    }

    //          console.log("new picture to center: "+picture_to_center);
                // FADE IN THE NEXT IMAGE
                $("#galleries ."+picture_to_center+" img").animate({opacity:1});
                return picture_to_center;   
    };

    // last picture for keyboard
    function scroll_to_the_new_picture_to_center(picture_to_center){
        // Stop the user to be able to canceled the presentation mode by scrolling or resizing the window
        // during the scrolling event
        // Not working properly -> need to check

    //  console.log(picture_to_center);
        console.log("scroll_to_the_new_picture_to_center");
        console.log("counter: "+counter);
        counter++;
        presentation_mode_stop_scrolling = "on";

        // Calculate the top margin to center the image inside the screen
        var window_height = $(window).height();
        var img_height = $("#galleries ."+picture_to_center+" img").height();
        var offset = (window_height-img_height)/2;
        var max = parseInt($("#galleries #pictures-content").length);
    //  console.log("max: "+max);

        // We are scrolling to the bottom of the page
        if(picture_to_center > max){
            // FADE IN ALL PICTURES
    //      picture_to_center = 0;
            z=1;
            $("#galleries #pictures-content").each(function() {
                $("#galleries ."+z+" img").animate({opacity:1});
                z++;
            });
            $("#header").animate({opacity:1});
            $("#description").animate({opacity:1});
            $("#bottom_site").animate({opacity:1});
            console.log("picture_presentation should be removed");
            $("#galleries").removeClass('picture_presentation');
            console.log("picture_presentation should be removed");
            $("body").scrollTo($(document).height(), 800, {
                onAfter: function(){
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        presentation_mode_stop_scrolling = "off";
    //                  console.log("presentation_mode_stop_scrolling: "+presentation_mode_stop_scrolling);         
                        $("#galleries #pictures-content").on('click',undisplay_center_pictures);                
                    },100);
                }
            });   
        }
        else{
             $("body").scrollTo($('.'+picture_to_center), 800, {
                offset:-offset,
                onAfter: function () {
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        presentation_mode_stop_scrolling = "off";
    //                  console.log("presentation_mode_stop_scrolling: "+presentation_mode_stop_scrolling);
    //                  $("#galleries #pictures-content").on('click'); -> not working, we need to specify the function                  
                        $("#galleries #pictures-content").on('click',undisplay_center_pictures);
                    },100);
                }
            });
        }
        return true;
    };
});
```

Comment: Do you have the exact same code inside window scroll and resize? `$(window).on('scroll resize', function `

Comment: The code is hard to read. Can you clean it up a bit, remove unnecessary comments etc. Is it possible to remove smth out of it but still be able to reproduce the error?

Comment: And btw I can't reproduce. What exactly are you clicking/pressing?

Comment: Normally, when you have several things that may cause the same event, you would define your own trigger, e.g. `$("#pictures-content img").on('highlightMe', function(){ /* procedure here */ })` and trigger it accordingly by itself `$('#pictures-content img').on('click', function(){ $(this).trigger('highlightMe'); });` or when required by any other event `$('#pictures-content img#number1').trigger('highlightMe'); });` This will help you separate things that happen to elements from things that cause things to happen, and maybe help you organise your code. (It's hard to follow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the .on method was used to cath the "keydown" and the "click" event, I had to unbind the "click" event on the "keydown" event.

```
    $(document).keydown(function(eventkeyboard) {
        eventkeyboard.preventDefault();
        $('#galleries #pictures-content').off('click');
... etc
```